# Show two set of dates in a chart for comparison

Tags: charts, dates, graphs, comparison, interactive-ui

I'm working on a graph that compares two date ranges, but based on the feedback I received, there's some confusion. It appears that the graph is being interpreted as spanning from January 1 to January 8, rather than the intended January 1 to January 7(check screenshot).

Could you provide any UI suggestions to clarify this? Please see the attached screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: You should investigate further why users interpret the bar chart wrong. An assumption of mine would be that the separation (yellow above, blue below the chart) is causing confusion. Group the blue and yellow labels and legend. But maybe there's more going on like ambiguity in language: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112082/is-to-inclusive-in-i-worked-at-company-x-from-april-2012-to-april-2013.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion using days like [Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat] as reference points instead of the exact date, because seeing 2 dates will for sure cause confusion. By using Days, it will help to compare this Monday vs last Monday and in legend we can show 1 Jan - 7 Jan & 8 Jan - 14 Jan. That way it is easy to distinguish.

Note: If it is not limited by 7 days then this format may not work